# Instagram ellipse icon not being recognised while using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, debugging, automation, bots, instagram

I have tried using and combining different forms including xpath, css selectors, labels, to be able to get the automation with selenium to recognize and click the key to show the next page others but to no avail.

```
ellipsis_icon = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='More options']"))). #xpath
```

```
ellipsis_icon = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Cx7Bp")))
#css selector
```

```
ellipsis_icon = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg[aria-label='More options']"))) #explicit wait
```

Comment: Can you please provide details, how that button can be found?

Comment: ellipsis_icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='More options']")       this is a code that should work